# create cassandra table for scala nested case class

Tags: scala, cassandra, lagom

I am storing a scala case class data in Cassandra table, for that, I need to define User-defined type. I can write cql query but do not know how to parse it.com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.UDT
    I have tried this annotation but it does not work me. I think I'm completely out of the track. 
    I have also tried Session class belong to `com.datastax.driver.core.Session.`
    and my conclusion is I have no idea how to do it I am just using hit and trail.

```
case class Properties(name: String,
label: String,
                           description: String,
                           groupName: String,
                           fieldDataType: String,
                           options: Seq[OptionalData]
                         )
object Properties{
  implicit val format: Format[Properties] = Json.format[Properties]
}


case class OptionalData(label: String, name: String)
object OptionalData{
  implicit val format: Format[OptionalData] = Json.format[OptionalData]
}
```

and my query is:

```
val optionalData: String=
    """
      |CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS optionaldata(
      |label text,
      |name text
      );
    """.stripMargin

   val createPropertiesTable: String =       """
                          |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS prop(
                          |name text Primary Key,
                          |label text,
                          |description text,
                          |groupname text,
                          |fielddatatype text,
                          |options LIST<frozen<optionaldata>>
                          );
                        """.stripMargin
```

> com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown typ
>       e leadpropdb3.optionaldata
>       java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown type leadpropdb3.optionaldata
>               at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
>               at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:513)
>               at akka.persistence.cassandra.package$ListenableFutureConverter$$anon$2.$anonfun$run$2(package.scala:25)
>               at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
>               at akka.persistence.cassandra.package$ListenableFutureConverter$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
>               at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: Unknown type leadpropdb3.optionaldata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From error message it's clear that the type wasn't created - you need to create it before creating the table - be very careful when executing CQL statements from your code - you need to wait until schema is an agreement, before you execute next statement. Here is an [example of Java code](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/com/datastax/alexott/demos/jdtest1/WhiteListPolicyExample.java#L37) that does this - it's easy to convert it into Scala.

When you're using Object Mapper with Scala, you need to obey some rules (I hope that my blog post on that topic will be published soon):

1. You need to use Java types - `List` instead of `Seq`, etc., or use [extra codecs for Scala](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-scala-extras);
2. Case classes should have empty constructor.

but otherwise it's possible to use object mapper with Scala, like this:

```scala
@UDT(name = "scala_udt")
case class UdtCaseClass(id: Integer, @(Field @field)(name = "t") text: String) {
  def this() {
    this(0, "")
  }
}

@Table(name = "scala_test_udt")
case class TableObjectCaseClassWithUDT(@(PartitionKey @field) id: Integer,
                                       udt: UdtCaseClass) {
  def this() {
    this(0, UdtCaseClass(0, ""))
  }
}

// ...
val mapperForUdtCaseClass = manager.mapper(classOf[TableObjectCaseClassWithUDT])
val objectCaseClassWithUDT = mapperForUdtCaseClass.get(new Integer(1))
println("ObjWithUdt(1)='" + objectCaseClassWithUDT + "'")
```

More examples are available in [my repo](https://github.com/alexott/dse-java-playground/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/ObjMapperTest.scala).

Comment: Thanks for helping me but it does not work for me. My problem is very simple i.e i just want to insert following scala case class object in cassandra db using BoundStatement.   case class student(name: String, games: List[Sports])                                                        case class Sports(name: String, desc: String). please help me out. I was stucked at the same point for two days.

Comment: If you want to go with bound statements, and bind case class directly to UDT, then you need to go the route of custom codecs - either automatically generated, or explicitly declared. Java driver manual describes this in great details: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/custom_codecs/#on-the-fly-codec-generation